# In-App Purchase: request products randomly get some valid product and some invalid products?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm doing the In-App purchase feature. Today I get a weird issue.

I try to get list products by `SKProductsRequest`. The problem is: sometimes I received `invalidProductIdentifiers`, but sometimes I received valid products.

`SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]  initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:objects]];
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];`

Ex: I send a request to get info of 30 products: sometimes get 10 products are valid, sometimes 0, sometimes 30, ... So weird.

In the past, it works well. But one day the problem occurs.

I tried (searched and asked my co-workers) a day but still can not figure out why.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.

"But one day the problem occurs". And one day, it disappeared.

I think it's the Apple's bug.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check your application id should not be with wild card (*), it cannot be enabled for In-App Purchases so make sure you should create a new App ID.

If above scenario is not your case, then you will have to wait for maximum 24 hours after creating new product id from your developer account, within this time your product id will be fetched from your application. Because some times apple takes time to enabled product ids.

If above  both are not your cases then at last you will have to check your product id’s are valid or invalid with below code.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest )request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse )response {

for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }
}
```

If you found your product ids are invalid please go through with http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

Cheers.....

Comment: Thank for your reply. But I tried all of your solutions and still fail. It isn't failling all. Just randomly fail some.

Comment: Currently, If you are test your application using iOS App Development provision profile so can you please create new Ad Hoc provision profile and test it? And also create new sandbox account for the same and use that one.